# React Testing Library is not detecting my title tag, but it actually exists

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

Basically I'm trying to check if when all the component is rendered, there's a "Filters" title in the screen, but React Testing Library for some reason is not detecting it and it just throws me that error.

I will let here all the code and an image of the error.

[image]

FilterBox.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './FiltersBox.css';

function FiltersBox({ onSortSelected, onCategorySelected }) {
    function sortByPrice(e) {
        onSortSelected(e.target.value);
    }

    function sortByCategory(e) {
        onCategorySelected(e.target.value);
    }

    return (
        <div className='items_container-filter_box'>
            <h3 className='filter_box-title'>Filters</h3>

            <div className='filter_box-filters_container'>
                <div className='filter_box-filter filter_box-first_filter'>
                    <h5>By Price:</h5>

                    <div className='filter_box-select'>
                        <select onChange={sortByPrice}>
                            <option value='none'>-</option>
                            <option value='ascending'>Ascending</option>
                            <option value='descending'>Descending</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className='filter_box-filter filter_box-second_filter'>
                    <h5>By Category:</h5>

                    <div className='filter_box-select'>
                        <select onChange={sortByCategory}>
                            <option value='none'>-</option>
                            <option value="men's clothing">Men&apos;s Clothing</option>
                            <option value="women's clothing">Women&apos;s Clothing</option>
                            <option value='jewelery'>Jewelery</option>
                            <option value='electronics'>Electronics</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

MainSection.test.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import MainSection from './MainSection.js';

beforeAll(() => {
    render(<MainSection />);
});

test('Check if renders the Search Bar', () => {
    const textInput = screen.getByTestId('text-input');

    expect(textInput).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(textInput).toHaveAttribute('type', 'text');
    expect(textInput).toHaveAttribute('placeholder', 'Search here!');
});

test('Check if renders the Filters Box', () => {
    const filterTitle = screen.getByText(/Filters/i);

    const filterLabelByPrice = screen.getByText(/by price:/i);
    const filterLabelByCategory = screen.getByText(/by category:/i);

    const filtersComboBoxes = screen.getAllByRole('combobox');

    expect(filterTitle).toBeInTheDocument();

    expect(filterLabelByPrice).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(filterLabelByCategory).toBeInTheDocument();

    expect(filtersComboBoxes).toHaveLength(2);
});
```

I tried everything without success.

**Update:**

I tried @nbjorling's user solution. And it works now, I think... Because it stills giving me the error but both tests just passed (green).

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Please post text, not images.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Can you also include the imports.

Comment: If you comment that one out, do you get stuck on the next one or can it find that one?

Comment: @nbjorling Oh... It gives me the same error with the others titles. But only in the "Filters Box" test.

Comment: I updated my answer down below. Could it be that FiltersBox is not rendered?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you don't actually render the Filter component then?

what happens if you try this.

```
beforeAll(() => {
    render(
      <MainSection>
          <FiltersBox />
      <MainSection>
    );
});
```

Or try set it up like this (with your correct imports ofc):

```
test("Check if renders the Filters Box", () => {
  render(<FiltersBox />);

  const filterTitle = screen.getByText(/Filters/i);
  const filterLabelByPrice = screen.getByText(/by price:/i);
  const filterLabelByCategory = screen.getByText(/by category:/i);
  const filtersComboBoxes = screen.getAllByRole("combobox");

  expect(filterTitle).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(filterLabelByPrice).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(filterLabelByCategory).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(filtersComboBoxes).toHaveLength(2);
});
```

Comment: The OP's code uses the `i` flag on the regex.

Comment: Hi @nbjorling, thank you so much for your answer. I tried with "/Filters/i" but it still gives me that error.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, didn't think of the `i` there.

Comment: It says that "<FiltersBox />" is not defined. I tried importing it and stills giving me that error :(

Comment: Try my new answer up there. and maybe comment out the beforeAll and the other tests.

Comment: This is very weird... I try that and both test just passed (green). But it stills giving me that error. I'm gonna let an image on the edit of my question.

Comment: Anyways... How is it possible? I mean, I didn't need to import the "Seach Bar" component for test that one, why is this component giving me so many problems just for check a few titles? :/

Comment: Did you solve it with using a render inside every test case?

Answer (score 0):

I think rendering components only a time before all don't make a test separate from each other.

use `debug();` before  `const filterTitle = screen.getByText(/Filters/i);`, it will give you an idea of what is rendered on screen.

or try another selector
Try using `getByRole('heading', {name: "Filter"});`

I hope, it will help!

Comment: Yeah I was reading more about this issue but when I see others code they test all components separated :/ my bad I guess... Thank you so much anyways :)